# Deploying a VS 2013 solution to an existing web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-deployment

Target Framework is 3.5 both on the web server and VS 2013. The existing web application is developed with VS 2008 and working smoothly. My solution is working nicely on local host. But when i deployed the solution to the server via ftp, i always face "could not load type:xxxx.aspx" error. I tried almost everything i see on several forums for the last 3 days(changing codebehind to codefile, web.config changes etc)

I think the solution to my problem may be:

Building solution locally, manually upload all aspx files, images, css files to the subdirectory. And manually upload all dll files to root/bin directory (or subdirectory/bin directory?)

Can anyone suggest anything for the supposed solution?

Comment: Which version of .net framework your existing application App Pool is using?

Comment: that "xxxx" type, does it happen to be an included DLL file? is it possible that the file which contains this type is not being copied to output folder?

Comment: xxxx is giris.aspx file. It also have giris.aspx.vb file which must be included in dll file i think.

Comment: try emptying the website folder on the server (using ftp) first, and then deploy again. there might be a version conflict. check if it helps with the issue

Comment: Thanks Banana, but i did that at least 5-6 times. It didn't helped.

Comment: did your website work on the server at any point before? or the error occurred right on the first attempt?

Comment: It never worked. The error appeared after the first deployement.

Comment: 3.5 is being used by existing application qamar. In fact, that was my first problem. I developed the application with Framework 4.5, then i noticed the existing application is using 3.5. On the other hand, hosting web servers max is 4.0. Then i wrote my application on 3.5 from the scratch. It was impossible to convert it from 4.5 to 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, i've solved my problem as follows.

My Project is a solution working under a subdirectory of the main web page. This subdirectory has a /bin directory and VS20013 is putting the dll files into this directory. I keep receiving "Could not load type.." errors in all my attempts. When i copied all of my dll files from subdirectories /bin directory to the main site /bin directory everything worked fine. Pity for the time i've spent for changing my code for five days.

Hope this helps to somebody...